# node.js: Convert json to array

Tags: node.js, json, request

[image: Table I am looking to create in memory...]

Doing a web request to TDA API and getting a JSON formatted return on a number of strike prices for a stock/ticker. I am unable to get to the individual strike prices details which are in a JSON array. Below is the output I am getting:

What I am trying to accomplish is taking the data from each strike (eg: 13.5, 14.0...) and create an in-memory columnar table/array so that I can use the data to evaluate/assess potential trades/executions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```json
{
  "symbol": "F",
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "underlying": null,
  "strategy": "SINGLE",
  "interval": 0,
  "isDelayed": true,
  "isIndex": false,
  "interestRate": 0.1,
  "underlyingPrice": 13.08,
  "volatility": 29,
  "daysToExpiration": 0,
  "numberOfContracts": 19,
  "putExpDateMap": {},
  "callExpDateMap": {
    "2021-09-03:2": {
      "13.5": [
        {
          "putCall": "CALL",
          "symbol": "F_090321C13.5",
          "description": "F Sep 3 2021 13.5 Call (Weekly)",
          "exchangeName": "OPR",
          "bid": 0.03,
          "ask": 0.04,
          "last": 0.04,
          "mark": 0.04,
          "bidSize": 207,
          "askSize": 655,
          "bidAskSize": "207X655",
          "lastSize": 0,
          "highPrice": 0.05,
          "lowPrice": 0.02,
          "openPrice": 0,
          "closePrice": 0.03,
          "totalVolume": 47477,
          "tradeDate": null,
          "tradeTimeInLong": 1630526399010,
          "quoteTimeInLong": 1630526399727,
          "netChange": 0.01,
          "volatility": 35.069,
          "delta": 0.169,
          "gamma": 0.64,
          "theta": -0.019,
          "vega": 0.003,
          "rho": 0,
          "openInterest": 73416,
          "timeValue": 0.04,
          "theoreticalOptionValue": 0.035,
          "theoreticalVolatility": 29,
          "optionDeliverablesList": null,
          "strikePrice": 13.5,
          "expirationDate": 1630699200000,
          "daysToExpiration": 2,
          "expirationType": "S",
          "lastTradingDay": 1630713600000,
          "multiplier": 100,
          "settlementType": " ",
          "deliverableNote": "",
          "isIndexOption": null,
          "percentChange": 20.12,
          "markChange": 0,
          "markPercentChange": 5.11,
          "inTheMoney": false,
          "mini": false,
          "nonStandard": false
        }
      ],
      "14.0": [
        {
          "putCall": "CALL",
          "symbol": "F_090321C14",
          "description": "F Sep 3 2021 14 Call (Weekly)",
          "exchangeName": "OPR",
          "bid": 0.01,
          "ask": 0.02,
          "last": 0.01,
          "mark": 0.02,
          "bidSize": 66,
          "askSize": 1468,
          "bidAskSize": "66X1468",
          "lastSize": 0,
          "highPrice": 0.02,
          "lowPrice": 0.01,
          "openPrice": 0,
          "closePrice": 0.01,
          "totalVolume": 3453,
          "tradeDate": null,
          "tradeTimeInLong": 1630526389748,
          "quoteTimeInLong": 1630526395218,
          "netChange": 0,
          "volatility": 49.446,
          "delta": 0.063,
          "gamma": 0.224,
          "theta": -0.013,
          "vega": 0.001,
          "rho": 0,
          "openInterest": 31282,
          "timeValue": 0.01,
          "theoreticalOptionValue": 0.015,
          "theoreticalVolatility": 29,
          "optionDeliverablesList": null,
          "strikePrice": 14,
          "expirationDate": 1630699200000,
          "daysToExpiration": 2,
          "expirationType": "S",
          "lastTradingDay": 1630713600000,
          "multiplier": 100,
          "settlementType": " ",
          "deliverableNote": "",
          "isIndexOption": null,
          "percentChange": -33.33,
          "markChange": 0,
          "markPercentChange": 0,
          "inTheMoney": false,
          "mini": false,
          "nonStandard": false
        }
      ],
      "14.5": [
        {
          "putCall": "CALL",
          "symbol": "F_090321C14.5",
          "description": "F Sep 3 2021 14.5 Call (Weekly)",
          "exchangeName": "OPR",
          "bid": 0,
          "ask": 0.01,
          "last": 0.01,
          "mark": 0.01,
          "bidSize": 0,
          "askSize": 386,
          "bidAskSize": "0X386",
          "lastSize": 0,
          "highPrice": 0.01,
          "lowPrice": 0.01,
          "openPrice": 0,
          "closePrice": 0.01,
          "totalVolume": 70,
          "tradeDate": null,
          "tradeTimeInLong": 1630520505930,
          "quoteTimeInLong": 1630526227626,
          "netChange": 0,
          "volatility": 60.163,
          "delta": 0.027,
          "gamma": 0.092,
          "theta": -0.008,
          "vega": 0.001,
          "rho": 0,
          "openInterest": 5529,
          "timeValue": 0.01,
          "theoreticalOptionValue": 0.007,
          "theoreticalVolatility": 29,
          "optionDeliverablesList": null,
          "strikePrice": 14.5,
          "expirationDate": 1630699200000,
          "daysToExpiration": 2,
          "expirationType": "S",
          "lastTradingDay": 1630713600000,
          "multiplier": 100,
          "settlementType": " ",
          "deliverableNote": "",
          "isIndexOption": null,
          "percentChange": 40.85,
          "markChange": 0,
          "markPercentChange": -4.23,
          "inTheMoney": false,
          "mini": false,
          "nonStandard": false
        }
      ],
      "15.0": [
        {
          "putCall": "CALL",
          "symbol": "F_090321C15",
          "description": "F Sep 3 2021 15 Call (Weekly)",
          "exchangeName": "OPR",
          "bid": 0,
          "ask": 0.01,
          "last": 0.01,
          "mark": 0,
          "bidSize": 0,
          "askSize": 594,
          "bidAskSize": "0X594",
          "lastSize": 0,
          "highPrice": 0.01,
          "lowPrice": 0.01,
          "openPrice": 0,
          "closePrice": 0,
          "totalVolume": 184,
          "tradeDate": null,
          "tradeTimeInLong": 1630524777537,
          "quoteTimeInLong": 1630526370053,
          "netChange": 0.01,
          "volatility": 68.916,
          "delta": 0.012,
          "gamma": 0.041,
          "theta": -0.005,
          "vega": 0,
          "rho": 0,
          "openInterest": 4867,
          "timeValue": 0.01,
          "theoreticalOptionValue": 0.003,
          "theoreticalVolatility": 29,
          "optionDeliverablesList": null,
          "strikePrice": 15,
          "expirationDate": 1630699200000,
          "daysToExpiration": 2,
          "expirationType": "S",
          "lastTradingDay": 1630713600000,
          "multiplier": 100,
          "settlementType": " ",
          "deliverableNote": "",
          "isIndexOption": null,
          "percentChange": 185.71,
          "markChange": 0,
          "markPercentChange": -8.57,
          "inTheMoney": false,
          "mini": false,
          "nonStandard": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the actual result you'd like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added table of 14.5 and 15 to the initial thread.... While the table I have given consists of all of the provided data points this could even be reduced as not all of the data points provided are things that will be assessed in this effort.

Comment: My issue with providing code is I have found nothing as to how to navigate the JSON. I have tried to use the json.parse, which didnt help. Really at a starting point with no clear direction on how to attack this. Being that this data is continually changing I am not looking to put it to file/disk/database as I have no reason to maintain it (Not interested in historical.). It will be evaluated and disposed of once the assessment is completed.